# Unity SpriteMask intersection

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to create a wheel segment by masking a sprite renderer (sky blue) with a circle sprite mask and a triangle sprite mask (orange borders):

[image: example image]

From everything I've tried with different custom ranges and sorting groups, I can't seem to find a way to stop both masks always being applied as shown in the image - I only want the intersection of these masks.

Is this kind of mask intersection possible to achieve with the Unity `SpriteMask` Component? Or can I only solve this kind of problem with shaders?